# Laravel - Can i add new item to an array based on the `id` value existing that array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

```
array (
   0 =>
    array (
    'courseId' => 14,
    'tutorName' => 'admin',
    ),
   1 =>
    array (
    'courseId' => 15,
    'tutorName' => 'merl',
    ),
 )
```

`var_export($response)` is an array like above. For each `courseId` in the `$response` array, i wanted to find `sum` of `points` when the `courseId` in the `$response` array exists `student_learning` table also. After that,  i wanted to add this sum of points(`$points`) to the `$response` array as a new item for the corresponding `courseId`. Here, the issue is that, every values of `$points` is added as a new item in every datasets of the `$response` array,but i wanted it to get added to the `$response` array of it's respective `courseId` only. How can i do that?

```
foreach ($response as $key ) {
           
     $points=DB::table('student_learning')->groupBy('courseId')->where('courseId',$key['courseId'])->sum('points');
     $res = array_map(function($e) use($points,$percent) { 
          $e['points'] = $points;
          return $e; }, $response);
    dump($res);
  }
```

`dump($res)` gives an output like below

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:8 [
    "courseId" => 14
    "tutorName" => "admin"
    "points" => 12
  ]
  1 => array:8 [
    "courseId" => 15
    "tutorName" => "me"
    "points" => 12
  ]
]
array:2 [
  0 => array:8 [
    "courseId" => 14
    "tutorName" => "admin"
    "points" => 3
  ]
  1 => array:8 [
    "courseId" => 15
    "tutorName" => "me"
    "points" => 3
  ]
]
```

`dump($res)` outside the `foreach` gives an output like below

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:8 [
    "courseId" => 14
    "tutorName" => "admin"
    "points" => 3
  ]
  1 => array:8 [
    "courseId" => 15
    "tutorName" => "me"
    "points" => 3
  ]
]
```

**Expected/Required Output**:

```
  [
    "courseId" => 14
    "tutorName" => "admin"
    "points" => 12
  ]
  [
    "courseId" => 15
    "tutorName" => "me"
    "points" => 3
  ]
```

Comment: So you need to add points to each array right ?

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai yes. pls see my expected output. That is what i wanted

Comment: Can you share the both table structures

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai i don't think answer will be connected to the table structure anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add new array key while looping using foreach

```
$response  = array (
   0 =>
    array (
    'courseId' => 14,
    'tutorName' => 'admin',
    ),
   1 =>
    array (
    'courseId' => 15,
    'tutorName' => 'merl',
    ),
 );

    $newResponse = [];
  foreach($response as $eachResponse){
    $points=DB::table('student_learning')->groupBy('courseId')->where('courseId',$eachResponse['courseId'])->sum('points');
    
    $eachResponse['points'] = $points;
    $newResponse[] = $eachResponse;
  }
dd($newResponse);
```